# Redirect between two application roots - Jersey

Tags: java, redirect, jersey, jax-rs

My application has two packages with different application roots.

First application root:

```
package application.config;

@ApplicationPath("users")
public class UsersApplicationRoot extends ResourceConfig {

    public UsersApplicationRoot() {
        packages("application");
    }
}
```

Second application root:

```
package webservice.config;

@ApplicationPath("service")
public class APIApplicationRoot extends ResourceConfig {

    public APIApplicationRoot() {
        packages("webservice");
     }
}
```

So my application is available at `<host>/service/*` and `<host>/users/*`.

The package `webservice` contains the following method:

```
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response login(@BeanParam LoginBean loginBean) throws URISyntaxException {

    String username = loginBean.getUsername();
    String password = loginBean.getPassword();

    URI indexPage = UriBuilder.fromUri("/index.html").build();
    URI userHome = UriBuilder.fromUri("/users/{username}").build(username);

    boolean authenticated = authenticate(username, password);

    if (authenticated){
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(userHome).build();
    } else {
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(indexPage).build();
    }
}
```

After an successful authentication the user should be redirected to the URI of the other application root `<host>/users/<username>` which GETs the request over the following class:

```
package application.servlets;

@Path("{username}")
public class UsersHomeServlet {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String showUsername(@PathParam("username") String username){

        return username;
    }
}
```

With this application structure I monitor a very odd behavior:

The method `login(..)` successfully performs a redirect and the method `showUsername(..)` is correctly called after that redirect - BUT the redirect has no impact of the page shown in the browser. Means that in my browser there is still the login form and not the `<host>/users/<username>` page where the redirect points to.